# Rails css asset pipeline not pulling in other stylesheets.

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

So I am building an application & I have added the `bootstrap-sass` gem. Here is what my gemfile looks like:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3',  '1.3.11'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

I my routes folder:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'landing_page#home'
  get 'users/new'
end
```

And I have two stylesheets `application.scss` & `landing_page.scss`.

I am simply trying to style my landing page. However, I am unable to get any of the styles from my `landing_page.scss` to load. I can only get these styles to load if placed in `application.scss`.

Here is `application.scss`

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */


@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

body{
  background-color: #525252;
}
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Why is it that sass or just plain css is not being applied when being placed in `landing_page.scss`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `@import` partial to sass file. See http://sass-lang.com/guide to know how partials work.

In your case, you should rename `landing_page.scss` to `_landing_page.scss` and do `@import landing_page` in the `application.scss` file.

Comment: I definitely understand how partials function and now have my application working appropriately, so thank you very much so! I'm interested in why this stylesheet has to be imported, I thought that it was originally part of the asset pipeline. Or is it because of the sass implementation?

Comment: are you asking why `landing_page.scss` not included along with `application.scss`?

Comment: Sprocket(or assets pipeline) reads manifest files to build a single css or js file. By default, the manifest file is application.css or application.scss. Because of that, you need to import(or include) other css snippets for them to be processed. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives. Does it answer your question?